# Shader de React Shadertoy no se actualiza

Tags: javascript, reactjs, glsl

Estoy usando el componente [Shadertoy](https://github.com/mvilledieu/shadertoy-react) en React para visualizar un shader en glsl. Al inicio se visualiza correctamente, pero si actualizo el shader (string) se sigue visualizando la versión anterior, a pesar de que el cambio si es recibido por el componente (lo compruebo imprimiendo la cadena con `<p>`.

Este es el código:

```js
function Shader(props) {
  useEffect(() => {}, [props.shader]);

  return (
    <>
      <Ratio ratio={1}>
        <ShadertoyReact fs={props.shader} />
      </Ratio>
      <p>{props.shader}</p>
    </>
  );
}
```

¿Es este el comportamiento esperado o estoy cometiendo algún fallo?

Gracias.

Comment: Hola! Bienvenidx a SOes. El idioma oficial es español, así que debo pedirte que traduzcas toooooooooooooda la pregunta (incluyendo el título!) 
para que otros te respondan y para que no termine cerrada. 
Recuerda que puedes [edit] la pregunta todas las veces que quieras.
Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el funcionamiento y ya de paso ganar tu primera medalla. 
Por otro lado, estaría bien que le echaras un vistazo a [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Solución

Una solución es forzar el renderizado del componente `ShadertoyReact`.

Para lograr esto puedes pasarle el atributo `key` al componente, ya que cuando éste cambie, react lo volverá a renderizar.

Esto sería:

```javascript
function Shader(props) {
  useEffect(() => {}, [props.shader]);

  return (
    <>
      <Ratio ratio={1}>
        <ShadertoyReact fs={props.shader} key={props.shader}/>
      </Ratio>
      <p>{props.shader}</p>
    </>
  );
}
```

### Explicación

Cada vez que el atributo `key` cambie, es decir, cuando cambies el prop `shader`, react volverá a renderizar el componente `ShadertoyReact` y por lo tanto estaras forzando a que se vuelva a construir dicho componente y que tome el cambio del shader.

---

Si esto no funciona directamente, entonces prueba creando un hook de estado (`useState`) para el shader:

```javascript
function Shader(props) {
  const [shader, setShader] = useState(props.shader);
  useEffect(() => {
   setShader(props.shader); // Cada vez que cambie el prop shader se actualizará el hook `shader`.
  }, [props.shader]);

// Utilizamos el hook en vez del prop (Aunque creo que debería funcionar en el ejemplo anterior sin el hook
  return (
    <>
      <Ratio ratio={1}>
        <ShadertoyReact fs={shader} key={shader}/>
      </Ratio>
      <p>{shader}</p>
    </>
  );
}
```

> ¿Es este el comportamiento esperado o estoy cometiendo algún fallo?

Al parecer el componente `ShadertoyReact` no está escuchando los cambios del atributo `fs` y por lo tanto no vuelve a renderizarse cuando hay un cambio en el mismo.

Comment: Muchas gracias, añadiendo el atributo key funciona.